# jQuery waypoint not firing on first item

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I'm using [waypoint.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) to detect when certain `<div>`s are scrolled past, changing the navigation class when they are. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
  Some text
</div>
<div class="section" id="section1">
  More text
</div>

<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#" id="trigger1">Go to section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="trigger2">Go to section 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('.section').waypoint(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('section','');
    $('ul#nav li a').removeClass('current');
    $('#trigger'+id).addClass('current');

});
```

This works, scrolling down and up, except that when I scroll right back to the top, the second menu item is still highlighted (still has the `current` class), whereas returning to the top *should* highlight the first menu item. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two times id="section1" 
Maybe this causes the problem?